# ignore full screen canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I have a canvas fullscreen over a webpage.
The size gets handled in processingjs.

```
        <div id="canvasDiv">
            <canvas id="processingCanvas" data-processing-sources="resources/processing/canvas01.pde"> </canvas>
        </div>
```

Behind the canvas is a lot of text. The problem is i can't scroll on a iPad anymore cause the canvas is on top.
Is there a way to ignore the canvas but still show it on top?
This is the current css:

```
#canvasDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}



#processingCanvas {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to let elements fall through to underlying elements:**

If the browser is Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Blackberry or Android, but not IE or Opera, you can use pointer-events to tell the canvas not to handle click/touch events and then the clicks/touches will be handled by the underlying elements. So, 
in CSS:

```
 #topCanvas{ pointer-events: none; }
```

But in IE and Opera, you have to be tricky:

- Hide top canvas,
- Trigger event on bottom element,
- Show top canvas.

This code shows how to trigger events on underlying elements:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#wrapper{ width:200; height:200;}
#bottom{ position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:200; height:200; background-color:red; }
#top{ position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:200; height:200; background-color:blue; }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    $('#top').click(function (e) {
        $('#top').hide();
        $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)).trigger("click");
        $('#top').show();
    });

    $("#bottom").click(function(){ alert("bottom was clicked."); });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <canvas id="bottom"></canvas>
        <canvas id="top"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```